# Humbleness in victory

Tags: single-word-requests

What word can I use for being humble in victory.

I recall their being a specific word for this, that was used in the context of battle, however, after some searching I've been unable to find a pertinent word.

Comment: Have you reviewed the guidance for [tag:single-word-requests]? Your question would be greatly stregthened, for example by including an example sentence that demonstrates how the word would be used, and what words you've considered and discarded. Are you the aggressor or defender in this battle? Are you showing humility to your own troops or to the vanquished? You might be *magnanimous*, or you might be *conciliatory*, or you might be *even-handed*, or you might merely be *noble*.

Comment: I see that I could have further elaborated. The word I was looking for was indeed *magnanimous*.

Answer (score 1):

> “Be humble in victory and gracious in defeat.”

― Christopher Earle (source:Goodreads)

Are you looking for the word gracious?

Other possibilities: modest, deferential, respectful, self-effacing

Comment: It was a single word; these generally work but aren't the word I was looking for.

Comment: Magnanimous? (different meaning than humble)

Comment: Yes! Apologies, for the incorrect description.

Comment: Only a word that matches OP's definition, not a word they may perhaps be looking for, is acceptable as an answer. 'Gracious' is defined by no dictionary I've checked in as 'humble in victory'.

Comment: Merriam Webster defines gracious as:Definition of gracious
1
a obsolete :  godly
b archaic :  pleasing, acceptable
2
a :  marked by kindness and courtesy a gracious host
b :  graceful
c :  marked by tact and delicacy :  urbane
d :  characterized by charm, good taste, generosity of spirit, and the tasteful leisure of wealth and good breeding gracious living. Edwin, you don't see that humble might fit under that umbrella? Nevermind, I'm sure you'll find some new way to argue with me. The OP didn't word their question correctly and I still found the word they were looking for.